# How to use a general method to solve this problem

Tags: sequence

Suppose $a_{n}>0(n=1,2,\cdots)$. The series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges and the constant $ \lambda \in\left(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Now I need to judge whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(n \tan \frac{\lambda}{n}\right) a_{2 n} $ is convergent or divergent (the answer is that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\left(n \tan \frac{\lambda}{n}\right) a_{2 n} $ is absolutely convergent)(1996).

```
Assuming[n > 0, 
 Refine[Normal[
   Series[Abs[(-1)^n (n*Tan[λ/n])], {n, Infinity, 1}]], 
  0 < λ < Pi/2]]
```

But the above code does not reveal the essence of this problem. How can I solve this problem in a more general way?

**Tips:**

$$n \tan \frac{\lambda}{n} a_{2 n} \sim \lambda a_{2 n}$$

Comment: `Series[Refine[Abs[(-1)^n (n*Tan[\[Lambda]/n] a[2 n])], 
   Assumptions -> {n \[Element] PositiveIntegers, 
     0 < \[Lambda] < Pi/2}], {n, Infinity, 1}] // Normal` manual calculate :)

Comment: (1) This is not really a Mathematica question. (2) The tail terms will be close to `lambda*a[2*n]` so asymptotically it is bounded by pairs of corresponding terms from the first series.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thank you very much for your comment. I think it is a good way to solve this kind of problem with function `Asymptotic`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct application of the [Limit Comparison Test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LimitComparisonTest.html):

```
DiscreteLimit[Abs[(-1)^n (n*Tan[λ/n] a[2 n])/a[2 n]], 
 n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < λ < Pi/2]
```

> ```
> (*  λ  *)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Asymptotic[Abs[(-1)^n (n*Tan[λ/n] a[2 n])], n -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> 0 < λ < Pi/2 && n > 0 && a[2 n] > 0]
```